# Evenlet monkey patch not working

Tags: python, eventlet

The code:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
import requests

def main():
    print(eventlet.patcher.is_monkey_patched(requests))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expected the print statement to return True but indeed it returned False.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's true, Eventlet does not patch `requests`, no need to. There is nothing special in this package with respect to green threads. Because it's basically a wrapper for `urllib3` providing nicer API. And then `urllib3` is not patched either, for same reason. We do, however, patch `socket`. `requests` is using `urllib3` which uses `socket` to create TCP connections and transfer data.

You can see list of modules patched by Eventlet at website http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html#monkeypatching-the-standard-library As of today (2016-04-09) it's: os, select, socket, thread, time, psycopg.
Soon `logging` will join this list.

I'd be happy to help you with the actual problem, that you think `is_monkey_patched` is solution for.

Comment: So when import requests=eventlet.import_patched('requests'), it does have have the cumulative effect of making requests api calls go green(by eventually patching socket) ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Two safe options are either `monkey_patch()` at first line in your program or `import_patched` anywhere.